# Can We identify If a View is a Toast or a Dialog? If Yes then How?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-toast

I m having a view instance, and programmatically I wanted to detect if the View is from a Toast message or View is a dialogue.
Toast object has a view object inside it. And we can also set a custom view to toast or dialogues.
But I don't have the instance of that toast object. I just have that view object and I want to detect if it is a toast or not.

Is there any way I can detect the above.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a view instance, then check like below

```
if (view instanceof Dialog){

 } else if (view instanceof Toast){

}
```

Comment: You will get cannot inconvertible type: cast View to Toast error.